# Configuring a submit button using AJAX that checks for the value of an incremented variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX properly to display an incremented value from a separate PHP file, but I'm a little iffy on the code. This is what it looks like:

```
$("#submit").click(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'info.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {$_SESSION['totalCorrect'}
      success: function()
      {
        if ($_SESSION['totalCorrect'] >= 8 && $_SESSION['totalCorrect'] <= 10) 
        {
          window.location.replace('success.php');
        }
        else
        {
          window.location.replace('retake.php');
        }
      }
      });
    });
```

The value is stored in `info.php` and I'm trying to pull that value from that file, but I'm not sure on how to code the AJAX syntax. I'm certain this `data: {$_SESSION['totalCorrect'}` code isn't correct.

I can display the incremented value so I know, at least, that the variable is being incremented, but what I want to do now is to use that variable to check if they passed or not. If they did, then they get redirected to `success.php`. If not, then they get sent to `retake.php`.

EDIT: `info.php`

```
if (empty($_SESSION["totalCorrect"]))
{
    $_SESSION["totalCorrect"] = 0;
}
else 
{
    $totalCorrect =  $_SESSION["totalCorrect"];
}

foreach ($correctAns as $key => $answer)
{
    if (!empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        if ($_POST[$key] == $answer)
        {
            echo $correct[$index];
            $_SESSION["totalCorrect"]++;    
        }
        else if($_POST[$key] != $answer)
        {
            echo $incorrect[$index];
        }
        $_SESSION[$key] = true;
    }
    $index++;
};
```

Comment: you're mixing php and js code (in success-callback). You cannot access `$_SESSION` in js-functions

Comment: Can I store `$_SESSION['totalCorrect']` in a variable that I can use to access?

Comment: can you show the main parts of `info.php`?

Comment: Updated it with `info.php`

Comment: I tried using `echo json_encode($totalCorrect)` inside the `info.php` file and changing the `$_SESSION['totalCorrect']` to `$totalCorrect` inside the AJAX call, but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps saying `$totalCorrect` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted all code, so I can only answer the one question.

*First*:
You're mixing php and javascript. You cannot access php variables in javascript unless you assign them as string to the output html or post them via an ajax - that's what you want to do.

So let's have a look at your jQuery-ajax:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'info.php',
     // dataType: 'json', // I deactivated this to recieve a string only

     // in data you should get the answers the user gave - another topic
     data: {question1: '42', question2: 'Douglas'}, // that ',' was missing

     // you'll get whatever you echo in info.php as 'result' as parameter 
     // in this success-callback-function (as result [json]):
     success: function(result) {
        // now you can check what the result is:
        console.log(result); // make it visible to you for debugging
        if (parseInt(result) >= 8 && parseInt(result) <= 10) {
          console.log('redirecting to SUCCESS');
          //window.location.replace('success.php'); // uncomment when working
        }
        else {
          console.log('redirecting to RETAKE');
          //window.location.replace('retake.php'); // uncomment when working
        }
     }
  });
});
```

now lets adjust your `info.php`:

```
if (empty($_SESSION["totalCorrect"]))
{
    $_SESSION["totalCorrect"] = 0;
}
else 
{
    $totalCorrect =  $_SESSION["totalCorrect"];
}

foreach ($correctAns as $key => $answer)
{
    // remember, that in $_POST you'll get everything you've put in 'data' before!
    if (!empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        if ($_POST[$key] == $answer) // better change to === if you know what data-types you'll get (and google the difference)
        {
            //echo $correct[$index]; // do not echo anything else but the result
            $_SESSION["totalCorrect"]++;    
        }
        else if($_POST[$key] != $answer)
        {
            //echo $incorrect[$index];
        }
    $_SESSION[$key] = true;
    }
    // $index++; // we don't need that, do we??
};

// here's the actual response/result: 
// All you echo will be in 'result' of your ajax succes-callback-function

echo $_SESSION["totalCorrect"];
```

I don't know what your form looks like, how all the pages are set up, so I can't provide a complete code - also this would go far beyond the question.
But this should give you an idea of how getting are variable from php via ajax works.

Further Info:
[Getting form data using JavaScript and sending data with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885747/getting-form-data-using-javascript-and-sending-data-with-ajax)

usefull stuff about json:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Yeah I couldn't post everything since they're several pages and I wanted to show the one that was giving me the issue. I think I was unclear on how PHP variables work with AJAX so I'm definitely taking a look at these links. You're answer also clarified some things so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped and you think I answered your question you might want to accept it..